# My Discord Bot doesn't start inside a thread (Discord.py)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, discord.py

So, I have coded a Discord Bot, but I want to run it in a thread, because I need pyramid for a webhook with GitHub. I will run it side by side, because the bot should write a message, when I push a update for my website hosted by GitHub Pages.

I got the pyramid server running but the bot wont start and when I try to run the bot normally, It runs quite nice.
The errors I got are:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/nikurasu/PycharmProjects/pyramidtest/test2.py", line 35, in discordthread
    client = MyClient()
  File "/home/nikurasu/PycharmProjects/pyramidtest/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() if loop is None else loop
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

I simplified the code to exclude other shitcode written by me, but even when I use that simple code, the bot do not want to run:

```
import threading
import discord
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response


def hello_word(request):
    return Response('Hello World')


def hello_jonas(request):
    return Response('<b>Hello, Jonas</b>')


def pyramidthread():
    with Configurator() as config:
        config.add_route('hello', '/')
        config.add_view(hello_word, route_name='hello')
        config.add_route('jonas', '/jonas')
        config.add_view(hello_jonas, route_name='jonas')
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)
    server.serve_forever()


def discordthread():
    token = 'nothing'

    class MyClient(discord.Client):
        async def on_ready(self):
            print('Eingeloggt als', self.user)

    print("Izuna versucht zu starten")
    client = MyClient()
    client.run(token)


t1 = threading.Thread(target=discordthread)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=pyramidthread)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I hope someone here can help me^^